# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified GULP (node js , keystone js )

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, keystonejs

I dont know why i am receiving this error AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified GULP (node js , keystone js ). What causes this error ? anyone can help ?. I am using keystone app and sass compilation?. gulp file that will restart keystonejs app and compile sass. Is this regarding on the gulp version my goal version in my package.json is "gulp": "^4.0.2",.

## My Gulp file

```
  var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var jshintReporter = require('jshint-stylish');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var shell = require('gulp-shell')
var bs = require('browser-sync').create();


var paths = {
    'src':['./models/**/*.js','./routes/**/*.js', 'keystone.js', 'package.json'],
    'style': {
        all: './public/styles/**/*.scss',
        output: './public/styles/'
    }
};

// gulp lint
gulp.task('lint', function(){
    gulp.src(paths.src)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter(jshintReporter));
});

// gulp watcher for lint
gulp.task('watch:lint', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.src)
        .pipe(watch())
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter(jshintReporter));
});

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src(paths.style.all)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.style.output))
    .pipe(bs.stream());
});

gulp.task('watch:sass', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.style.all, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
  bs.init({
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000',
    port: '4000'
  });
});

gulp.task('runKeystone', shell.task('node keystone.js'));

gulp.task('watch', ['watch:sass', 'watch:lint']);
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'runKeystone', 'browser-sync']);
```

Comment: Have you tried looking for an answer here on stackoverflow? This question has been asked and answered many many times.

Comment: i did use webpack instead